# Regarding the issue of Analyzing… not finishing during Flutter development in VSCode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I had noticed that VSCode had been sluggish lately, but since this morning, the Analyzing… process has not been completing. As a result, I'm unable to use various features of the IDE. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling VSCode once, but the issue persists. What can I do to resolve this problem?
Also, when I opened other projects in VSCode, I was able to use them without any issues.

Additionally, the `Dart Language Server` also seems to be running indefinitely.

Furthermore, the following process doesn't conclude either:
`Saving 'search_location_controller.dart': Running 'Dart' Formatter (configure).`

`flutter doctor`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.0, on macOS 13.5)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.81.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

Comment: does this happen for a new, bare project?

Comment: Thank you for the comment.
The issue was caused by a simple code mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It was a mistake in the freezed code.

```dart
@freezed
class GoogleApiKeyState with _$GoogleApiKeyState {
  const factory GoogleApiKeyState({
    required String? apiKey,
  }) = GoogleApiKeyState;　  // <- this
  const GoogleApiKeyState._();
}
```

❌:`}) = GoogleApiKeyState;`

⭕️`}) = _GoogleApiKeyState;`